# value attribute for lxml.html

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Here is my code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
#code
print fromstring(s).xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[4]')
```

Ouput is `[<InputElement 2946d20 name='question' type='hidden'>]`

How can I output the value? Any attribute for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post the sample input you are parsing? This would help greatly to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general with [lxml](http://lxml.de/) you can access an element's value directly via the `.value` attribute:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> s = """<input type="hidden" name="question" value="1234">"""
>>> doc = fromstring(s)
>>> doc.value
'1234'
```

In your case you'll also need to access the first element of the resulting list from your [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query:

```
print fromstring(s).xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[4]')[0].value
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done directly from XPath -- no need to change your surrounding Python.

```
print fromstring(s).xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[4]/text()')
```