# href attribute for lxml.html

Tags: python-3.4, lxml.html

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469785/value-attribute-for-lxml-html#22469878):

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> s = """<input type="hidden" name="question" value="1234">"""
>>> doc = fromstring(s)
>>> doc.value
'1234'
>>> doc.name
'question'
```

I tried to get both the link and the text from this code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
s = '<a href="http://a.com" rel="bookmark">bla bla bla</a>'
doc = fromstring(s)
print (doc.href)
print (doc.text_content())
```

It gives a `AttributeError:'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'href'`

Im new in lxml. Actually what was the problem?

How can i have both the link (a.com) and the text (bla bla bla) as strings from this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code works for me

```
from lxml.html import document_fromstring
doc = document_fromstring('<a href="http://a.com" rel="bookmark">bla bla bla</a>')
print (doc.xpath("//a")[0].get("href"))
print (doc.text_content())
```

Output:

```
http://a.com
bla bla bla
```

Comment: do you know why the <input> tag does behave like that and <a> doesn't? @ValeriyG